# registerUserNotificationSettings doesn't display alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert, uilocalnotification

I'm asking the user for permission to use local notifications on iOS 8 like this:

```
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
    UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
```

And I'm handling like this in my AppDelegate:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didRegisterUserNotificationSettings" object:nil];
}
```

But no alert is shown? It skips right to the delegate callback. Why is this? I'm doing this in the iOS simulator.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the app open? On iOS, alerts typically don't show if they are fired while the application is running...

Comment: Yeah, it's running. So I have to ask for permission during app startup instead?

Comment: Yes, and you're using the wrong class to send notifications. `NSNotificationCenter` is used to notify other parts of your program -- you're looking for `UILocalNotification` to notify **the user**.

Comment: See [here](http://thecodeninja.tumblr.com/post/89942124085/notifications-in-ios-8-part-1-using-swift-what) for a tutorial. It uses Swift, but you can translate it to Objective-C fairly easily.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding a little. I use registerUserNotificationSettings to ask the user for permission, which sends a callback to my AppDelegate that sends an NSNotification back to one of the running ViewControllers which updates a UISwitch based on that NSNotification

Comment: @SevenBits asking the user for permission to post notifications during app launch seems like a very bad idea to me. That gives the user no context at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert showing only once, to show it again on Simulator should press `iOS Simulator` -> `Reset Contents and Settings`